# Invoke a Method anonymous class

Tags: c#, generics

I am quite new to the C# world and I apologize if the Question title not exactly match the content. But now to my Problem:

I have the following construct:

```
    public interface IClass<TEnum>
    {
        Dictionary<TEnum, ISecondClass> dictionary { get; }
    }

    public abstract class ClassBase<TEnum> : IClass<TEnum>
    {
    public abstract Dictionary<TEnum, ISecondClass> dictionary { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteClass : ClassBase<ConcreteClass.Concrete>
    {
        public override Dictionary<Concrete, ISecondClass> dictionary { get; protected set; }

        public enum Concrete : ulong
        {

        }
    }

    public class OtherClass : ClassBase<OtherClass.Other>
    {
        public override Dictionary<Concrete, ISecondClass> dictionary { get; protected set; }

        public enum Other : ulong
        {

        }
    }
```

My goal is to instantiate all existing concrete classes based on it's enums, store all instances in a dictionary and later invoke some methods on each object.
I am not sure if this is even possible?

I am glad for any hint on this!

Comment: Are you saying you want the dictionary to globally keep track of each instance of the class?

Comment: There are a lot of options here. It might help if you showed us what you want the code that  "invoke(s) some methods" to look like

Comment: BTW, I notice the Dictionary in OtherClass is `Dictionary<Concrete, ISecondClass>`. Should it be `Dictionary<Other, ISecondClass>`?

Comment: @justin yes you are right. I will correct this. @conrad OK, I will do this as soon as I am back to my Notebook. I am on my Smartphone at The moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, it sounds like a version of the [Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern#C.23). You may find it useful to research that.

From Wikipedia's example Multiton code:

```
class FooMultiton
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, FooMultiton> _instances = new Dictionary<object, FooMultiton>();

    private FooMultiton() {}

    public static FooMultiton GetInstance(object key)
    {
        lock (_instances)
        {   
            FooMultiton instance;
            if (!_instances.TryGetValue(key, out instance))
            {
                instance = new FooMultiton();
                _instances.Add(key, instance);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This isn't directly pasteable into your class, but since you're looking for hints, I think it should point you in the right direction.

One word of caution about the above code: The method `GetInstance` will alter the dictionary if `key` isn't found. Personally, I associate the "Get" prefix with read-only methods. I'd either rename `GetInstance` or split it into two methods.

I'm not really sure what you mean by "instantiate all existing concrete classes based on it's enums", though. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but that is not exactly my problem. I think I need to post more code to descripe all aspects of my problem.

Comment: My Question and the title are not so well chosen so your answer is the closest one to what I am looking for. By the time I figured out how to invoke the methods by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Activator.CreateInstance()` to create concrete classes' objects and store them into dictionary.

Pass your `string classname from Enum` and create dynamic class objects. Store them into `Dictionary<Enum, ISecondClass>`

```
myObject = (MyAbstractClass)Activator.CreateInstance("AssemblyName", "TypeName");

or

var type = Type.GetType("MyFullyQualifiedTypeName");
var myObject = (MyAbstractClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

While retrieving, based on your enum key, you know what type of instance value represents.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought. But I want to use one loop to handle all and then I cant type the concrete baseclass coz all implementing another enum, based on the concrete class. I will try to repost some code, I see that what I've posted don't show all aspects of my problem. But I need to do this when I am not on my smartphone. Tomorrow I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand a goal of the sample code, but you can write some thing like this:

```
public interface IClass
{
    void MethodToDynamicInvoke();
}

public abstract class ClassBase<T>
    : IClass
{
    private Dictionary<Type, List<IClass>> instances = new Dictionary<Type, List<IClass>>();

    public ClassBase()
    {
        List<IClass> list;
        if (!instances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
        {
            list = new List<IClass>();
            instances.Add(typeof(T), list);
        }

        list.Add(this);
    }

    public abstract void MethodToDynamicInvoke();

    public void InvokeMetodOnClassesWithSameEnum()
    {
        List<IClass> list;
        if (instances.TryGetValue(EnumType, out list))
        {
            foreach (var instance in list)
            {
                instance.MethodToDynamicInvoke();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ConcreteClass
    : ClassBase<ConcreteClass.Concrete>
{
    public ConcreteClass()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void MethodToDynamicInvoke()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public enum Concrete : ulong
    {
    }
}

public class OtherClass : ClassBase<OtherClass.Other>
{
    public OtherClass()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void MethodToDynamicInvoke()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public enum Other : ulong
    {

    }
}
```