# How to capture arguments returned by dll events (events are subscribed using Reflection)?

Tags: c#, winforms, appdomain, system.reflection

I have  a winform application(WindowsFormsApplication2) that loads a dll using appdomain. In the winform, I have suscribed to 'TestEvent' implemented in ClassLibrary.dll. If the TestEvent returns an argument,how can I capture the returned argument in the event handler HandleEvent implemented in winform?

This is the winform application codes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ClassLibrary1;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("HandleEvent called");
        }
        string DLL = @"..\ConsoleApplication1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loader.Call( DLL, "ClassLibrary1.Class1", "RaiseEvent", HandleEvent, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            this.Close();
        }
     
    }

    public class Loader : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");
        object CallInternal(string dll, string typename, string method, EventHandler handler, object[] parameters)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
            object o = a.CreateInstance(typename);
            Type t = o.GetType();

            // Subscribe to the event
            EventInfo eventInfo = t.GetEvent("TestEvent");
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(o, handler);

            MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod(method);
            return m.Invoke(o, parameters);
        }

        public static object Call( string dll, string typename, string method, EventHandler handler, params object[] parameters)
        {
            Loader ld = (Loader)ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
            object result = ld.CallInternal(dll, typename, method, handler, parameters);
            AppDomain.Unload(ad);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ClassLibrary1.dll codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Class1
    {
        public event EventHandler TestEvent;

        public int RaiseEvent(string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                TestEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the exception is: " + ex.ToString());
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("the inner exception is: " + ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            return 2;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "TestEvent returns an argument"? Do you refer to the EventArgs parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
        void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("HandleEvent called");
        }

        string DLL = @"..\ConsoleApplication1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll";    
        //You can can create new appDomain: var dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain name");//If you really need it!
        var dom = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var assembly = dom.Load(DLL);

        var type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(p => p.FullName == "ClassLibrary1.Class1");
        var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var eventInfo = type.GetEvent("event name");
        var handleEventMethod = GetType().GetMethod("HandleEvent");
        Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, type, handleEventMethod);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(inst, handler);
        
        var method = type.GetMethod("RaiseEvent");
        var resultData = (int)method.Invoke(inst, new object[]{"Expecting argument of your method"});
```

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method?rq=1)

[Invoke a method of anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746055/invoke-a-method-anonymous-class)

[Subscribe to an event with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104789/subscribe-to-an-event-with-reflection)

[Invoke static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825355/how-to-invoke-static-method-in-c4-0-with-dynamic-type)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your want your `HandleEvent` method to be able to consume or produce some custom value that we'll call `Argument`. In this case, the outcome can be achieved by inheriting `EventArgs` for a custom event.

```
public class Class1
{
    public event ValueReceivedEventHandler TestEvent;

    public int RaiseEvent(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            TestEvent?.Invoke(
                this, 
                new ValueReceivedEventArgs{ Argument = msg } );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the exception is: " + ex.ToString());
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the inner exception is: " + ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Custom event args class

```
public delegate void ValueReceivedEventHandler(Object sender, ValueReceivedEventArgs e);
public class ValueReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Argument { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then you can handle event in one of these ways:

```
void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(e is ValueReceivedEventArgs ePlus)
     {
          Debug.WriteLine(ePlus.Argument.ToString());
     }
}


void HandleEvent(object sender, ValueReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Argument.ToString());
}
```

Please leave me a comment if this is way off from what you're trying to achieve.